# How to have a default sort on a datatable column while using window.dtDefaultOptions

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, datatables

I am looking for a method to have my table pre-sorted by date descending on the date column. I have gone through the datatables documentation on sorting but have not found a workable solution when using `window.dtDefaultOptions`.  It seemed like `window.dtDefaultOptions.order = [[3, "desc"]]` should be the way to accomplish this but it didn't work for me.

I have also tried `window.dtDefaultOptions.columnDefs = [{orderable: true, targets: 3}]` but that didn't solve the problem either.

This is my code in my index.blade:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.dtDefaultOptions.ajax = '{!! route(' admin.feedback.index ') !!}';
    window.dtDefaultOptions.stateSave = true;
    //window.dtDefaultOptions.scrollY = '50vh';
    window.dtDefaultOptions.scrollCollapse = true;

    window.dtDefaultOptions.order = [[3, "desc"]];

    window.dtDefaultOptions.columns = [{
            data: 'user.name',
            name: 'user.name'
        }, {
            data: 'type',
            name: 'type'
        }, {
            data: 'comment',
            name: 'feedback.comment'
        }, {
            data: 'date',
            name: 'created_at'
        }, {
            data: 'actions',
            name: 'actions',
            searchable: false,
            sortable: false
        }
    ];
    window.dtDefaultOptions.buttons = [];
    processAjaxTables();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the column to order by descending upon rendering.

```
window.dtDefaultOptions = {
            columnDefs: [],
            "order": [3,'desc'],
        };
```

The problem is that to get it to work I have to delete or comment out the saveState and scrollCollapes lines of code.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.dtDefaultOptions.ajax = '{!! route('admin.feedback.index') !!}';
        window.dtDefaultOptions = {
            columnDefs: [],
            "order": [3,'desc'],
        };
        //window.dtDefaultOptions.stateSave = true;
        //window.dtDefaultOptions.scrollY = '50vh';
        //window.dtDefaultOptions.scrollCollapse = true;
        window.dtDefaultOptions.columns = [{
             data: 'user.name', 
             name: 'user.name'
         }, {
             data: 'type', 
             name: 'type'
         }, {
             data: 'comment', 
             name: 'feedback.comment'
         }, {
             data: 'date', 
             name: 'created_at'
         }, {
             data: 'actions', 
             name: 'actions', searchable: false, sortable: false
         }
      ];
        window.dtDefaultOptions.buttons = [];
        processAjaxTables();
    });
```

So we have an answer that works for the stated question but it breaks other aspects of the code. In this case, I can live with this since the column order is more important than stateSave and scrollCollapse on this particular table. But if anyone knows how to achieve the column order along with stateSave, and scrollCollapse I would be interested in learning.